Bash command fails when part of it is coming from a variable
There are so many similar questions but nothing I tried seems to apply in this awfully simple case.
This is part of a long script but I'll try to summarise, in a nutshell:
This command works:
ffmpeg -v warning -stats -i "${working}" -vf "scale=-1:${CONVERT_HEIGHT}" -c:v libx265 -c:a aac -preset slow -x265-params "crf=22:min-keyint=25:keyint=50" "$writeTo"

If I try to pass preset as a variable like this:
SLOW_PRESET="-preset slow"
ffmpeg -v warning -stats -i "${working}" -vf "scale=-1:${CONVERT_HEIGHT}" -c:v libx265 -c:a aac $SLOW_PRESET -x265-params "crf=22:min-keyint=25:keyint=50" "$writeTo"

it fails with:
Unrecognized option 'preset slow'.
Error splitting the argument list: Option not found

I tried debugging it with set -x and relevant part of the script is here:
+ CURRENT_RES=720
+ writeTo='sometarget.mp4'
+ original='somesource.wmv'
+ working='some.tmp'
+ [[ 720 -gt 1080 ]]
+ SLOW_PRESET='-preset slow'
+ ffmpeg -v warning -stats -i 'somesource.wmv' -c:v libx265 -c:a aac '-preset slow' -x265-params crf=22:min-keyint=25:keyint=50 'sometarget.mp4'

Please note the long ffmpeg command is not saved as a string, its directly running. I've also tried using "$SLOW_PRESET" and ${SLOW_PRESET} which changed nothing.
Shell version: GNU bash, version 5.2.15(1)-release (x86_64-slackware-linux-gnu)
Edit: I have added debug output of ffmpeg line which looks like adding single quotes, which I guess is my problem. Do I have to change the way I set the variable? Also looks like the double quotes in the original command is converted to single quotes as well, but from testing I can tell this does not cause a problem.

The relevant part of the set -x output is the ffmpeg line, which you left out.

Does your script change IFS? Also, are you sure the script is running in bash, not zsh (scripts don't always run in the same shell as what you use interactively)?

I know you put the bash version in the question, but the symptom seems like you ran the script with zsh, which doesn't do word-splitting when expanding variables.

Also sh != bash since you posted the sh version: GNU bash, version 5.2.15(1)-release (x86_64-slackware-linux-gnu

I suspect @GordonDavisson is on the right track asking about IFS. Anyway, the solution in general is to use an array when putting multiple arguments in a variable, as it also solves the problem when you need explicit spaces in the arguments. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12136948/why-does-shell-ignore-quoting-characters-in-arguments-passed-to-it-through-varia?noredirect=1&lq=1

I cannot replicate this error message by setting variables and running those two lines. Please edit your question to give a [mcve] for people to test.

@Barmar I've added the missing ffmpeg line. @GordonDavisson yes I am setting IFS IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b") and script is 100% running with bash and not zsh (it's a very limited distribution of slackware does not even have zsh)

That's not a good IFS setting. It only has newline and backspace, it doesn't have space. So $SLOW_PRESET won't be split into separate words at the space character.

BTW, there's no need to use echo -en. Use $'\n\b'

Why are you changing IFS in the first place?

Regardless of all that, use the array solution in the linked question. SLOW_PRESET=(-preset slow) and then "${SLOW_PRESET[@]}" in the ffmpeg line.

@Barmar the exclusion of space is intentional. I actually only need that IFS in a limited part of the script but setting it at the beginning. I can potentially juggle it around to set/reset in various different places. But it looks like the array solution you mentioned works. Thank you very much!

I'm guessing you're setting it for the benefit of read statements. But you need to be aware that it also applies when expanding variables, so you have to be careful.

Usually people use something like IFS='whatever' read ... so it only applies to that statement and doesn't have a pervasive effect.

Nonstandard values of IFS can have all sorts of weird effects, and should be avoided or at least limited whenever possible. If you need to set it to something else, either isolate that setting to the relevant operation (e.g. IFS=$'\n\b' read ... as @Barmar suggested), or reset it back to normal as soon as possible. (Mind you, using an array instead of depending on word splitting is also a good idea, even if you aren't messing with IFS.)
